# iPhone refactoring with ivar names

Tags: iphone, objective-c, dynamic, instance-variables

Could anyone tell me how I can dynamically specify an ivar name within my method?
l2 is the ivar I'm trying to target.

```
//this works
if (maxunlocked > 1) { 

filename = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"level%d.png", [[fliesArray objectAtIndex:2] intValue]];
filenameHi = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"level%dHi.png", [[fliesArray objectAtIndex:2] intValue]];

l2 = [SoundMenuItem itemFromNormalSpriteFrameName:filename selectedSpriteFrameName:filenameHi target:self selector:@selector(level:)];

}
```

//this doesn't

```
    for (int i = 0; i<11; i++) {

    if (maxunlocked > i) {

    filename = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"level%d.png", [[fliesArray objectAtIndex:i] intValue]];
    filenameHi = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"level%dHi.png", [[fliesArray objectAtIndex:i] intValue]];


//this is where I'm attempting to dynamically specify the SoundMenuItem instance name.  
    sndMenuItem = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"l%d", i];

    sndMenuItem = [SoundMenuItem itemFromNormalSpriteFrameName:filename selectedSpriteFrameName:filenameHi target:self selector:@selector(level:)]; 
    sndMenuItem.userData = (id)i;
     }
    }
```

Thanks,

Mark

Comment: It might help if you show where `l2` is created.

Answer (score 1):

If you have it declared as a property, you may be able to use KVC to get it.

```
float h1 = [object height];
float h2 = [[object valueForKey:@"height"] floatValue];
```

---

[EDIT]

I didn't understand what you're saying.  The answer is no.  You can't specify a variable name dynamically.  What you can do is this:

```
// if `l2` is a member of self. (as in self.l2)
for (int i = 0; i<11; i++) {

    if (maxunlocked > i) {

    filename = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"level%d.png", [[fliesArray objectAtIndex:i] intValue]];
    filenameHi = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"level%dHi.png", [[fliesArray objectAtIndex:i] intValue]];


//this is where I'm attempting to dynamically specify the SoundMenuItem instance name.  
    key = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"l%d", i];

    tmp = [SoundMenuItem itemFromNormalSpriteFrameName:filename selectedSpriteFrameName:filenameHi target:self selector:@selector(level:)]; 
    tmp.userData = (id)i;

    [self setValue:tmp forKey:key];
     }
    }
```

---

[EDIT]

You should probably re-structure your entire class.

```
@interface myViewController: NSViewController {
    UIButton *sound1;
    UIButton *sound2;

    SoundMenuItem *l1;
    SoundMenuItem *l2;
}

@property (assign) IBOutlet UIButton *sound1; // connect up in IB
@property (assign) IBOutlet UIButton *sound2;

- (IBAction) clickSoundButton: (id)sender; // connect up to sound1 and sound2 in IB
- (SoundMenuItem) getSoundMenuItem: (int) i;

@end

@implementation myViewController

- (IBAction) clickSoundButton: (id)sender
{
   if (sender == (id)sound1) l1 = [self getSoundMenuItem: 1];
   if (sender == (id)sound2) l2 = [self getSoundMenuItem: 2];
}

- (SoundMenuItem) getSoundMenuItem: (int) i
{
if (maxunlocked <= i) return

    NSString *filename = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"level%d.png", [[fliesArray objectAtIndex:i] intValue]];
    NSString *filenameHi = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"level%dHi.png", [[fliesArray objectAtIndex:i] intValue]];

    SoundMenuItem *sndMenuItem = [SoundMenuItem itemFromNormalSpriteFrameName:filename selectedSpriteFrameName:filenameHi target:self selector:@selector(level:)]; 
    sndMenuItem.userData = (id)i;
    return sndMenuItem; //(assuming it is auto-released)
}
@end
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply but I'm not sure how I can use this?
I'm trying to dynamically specify a pointer name (l2)

Comment: @crooksy88, you can't actually do that.  The closest you can get is specifying a key in a Dictionary.

Comment: OK, so I now have a dictionary of key/value pairs, and l2 = soundMenuItem within the dict. How would I now set my l2 pointer to equal the key/value?

Comment: Is `l2` a member of a class?  use `[self setValue:tmp forKey:key]` instead of the dictionary.  I didn't know where `l2` was stored.

Answer (score 0):

After the question was clarified my first answer was not valid. The answer by @stephen with the suggestion for using a dictionary to keeping all the SoundMenuItem is what I would have proposed as well.

Comment: @Stephen, If that is the case than that is also possible using class_addIvar()

Comment: yes it is.  I'm not sure AOP is necessary for this though, I think KVC should fix it.

Comment: @Stephen, on that I totally agree. I'm pretty sure this is overkill and not the actual intent of the question.

Answer (score 0):

Sorry about the lack of info and thanks for your patience. I was struggling to add it all into the comments area due to the character limit.

This is what I'm attempting...

In my header file:

//SoundMenuItem is a class
    SoundMenuItem *l1;
    SoundMenuItem *l2; (I actually have 20 buttons, one for each game level)

In my .m file

```
//here I set up the l1 button which is never locked
l1 = [SoundMenuItem itemFromNormalSpriteFrameName:filename selectedSpriteFrameName:filenameHi target:self selector:@selector(level:)];

//and here I set the l2 button to be locked by default  
l2 = [SoundMenuItem itemFromNormalSpriteFrameName:@"levellock.png" selectedSpriteFrameName:@"levellockHi.png" target:self selector:@selector(doNothing:)];
```

//now I check to see if level2 has been unlocked (maxunlocked > 1) and if so I reset the l2 instance to use different images.

if (maxunlocked > 1) {

filename = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"level%d.png", [[fliesArray objectAtIndex:2] intValue]];
filenameHi = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"level%dHi.png", [[fliesArray objectAtIndex:2] intValue]];

l2 = [SoundMenuItem itemFromNormalSpriteFrameName:filename selectedSpriteFrameName:filenameHi target:self selector:@selector(level:)];

}

So rather than having 20 iterations of the above if statement, one for each button I'm wanting to refactor it into one.

I hope I've made myself clearer.

Comment: You can edit the question and put new question text there instead.

Comment: I edited my question to help you out.  In the future, put edits like this in your question.  The space below is reserved for answers.